# Caching packages for npm install

Tags: node.js, azure-pipelines, npm-install

`npm install` hangs for a long time trying to fetch a file from npm registry https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk, is there any way to cache this file to speed up this process? I'd install the security package globally but from the log output, it doesn't show the package name (I'm pasting below part of the log of interest).

```
[...]
npm timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 17934ms
npm timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 17945ms
[...]
```

I'm building a node project on an Azure Pipeline in a private host. When the Job Task to install npm packages runs the Azure Agent most likely kills the process because it's taking too long failing the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [blog](https://samiprogramming.medium.com/cache-your-npm-install-on-azure-devops-b45ead758c00) you can refer to, you can get help from it.

You can use the caching solution from [Microsoft DevLabs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=1ESLighthouseEng.PipelineArtifactCaching). Add the task before the npm install. The first run takes longer, because the cache needs to be saved.
[image]

Node modules caching in Azure DevOps will reduce your pipeline run duration when your solution relies on node packages.

For details, you can also refer to [this](https://xebia.com/blog/caching-your-node-modules-in-azure-devops/).

To speed up first npm install, as a workaround, we could use `yarn install` or `pnpm install`-88% + 80% faster than npm install. For details, please refer to this [blog](http://www.tiernok.com/posts/2019/faster-npm-installs-during-ci/).

Comment: That's great Hugh, thank you. But I'm still having problems getting the first `npm install` executed successfully as the task is killed by the agent. The private server is a DO droplet so I don't think internet connection is the problem and I'm testing on a brand new angular project with no extra packages added. I'd like to keep this question open to see if someone could tell if installing any global npm package would skip that file fetch.

Comment: Is 60 minutes not enough to complete the job? Usually the [timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#timeouts) of the job is 60 minutes. We can set this in [Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uneP.png).

Comment: Apparently, if there's no log output change from the process for more than 30 seconds the task is killed even though the Task timeout is greater than that. I've just tried installing packages with Yarn and the pipeline has passed. Yarn was much faster, comparing Yarn to npm is like comparing a Hayabusa with an old bicycle. Although it's still just a workaround.

Comment: Indeed, using yarn install is a good workaround, Use `yarn install` or `pnpm install`-88% + 80% faster than npm install. Here is a [blog](http://www.tiernok.com/posts/2019/faster-npm-installs-during-ci/) about speeding up npm install. You can convert this workaround into an answer.